# How to upload single files and multiple Files using ng2-fileupload

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload single files from a list of multiple files, using `ng2-file-upload`. But then, only the first file I try to upload actually gets uploaded. How do I go about solving this issue? Thanks.

```js
singleUpload(fileName, item) {
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/uploadDocument', {
    photo_image: fileName,
    user_id: this.userid

  }).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(fileName);
    this.uploader.uploadItem(item); // it only uploads file to sever once

    popupS.alert({
      title: 'Feedback',
      content: '<br><hr><div align="center">' + fileName + ' has been <br> 
      Uploaded < /div><hr><br>'
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any error console browser?

Comment: please add your code on stackblitz

Comment: No, there's no error in the console

Comment: https://angular-s4ytec.stackblitz.io